# Can Apple's Accelerate Framework convolute non-constant kernel?

Tags: ios, c, kernel, convolution, accelerate-framework

This is my first StackOverflow question so please bear with me.

I am trying to use Apple's accelerate framework for image processing, and I have no trouble using it for constant value kernel convolution. But right now I run into problem when the kernel is not constant.

For example, I have a kernel that is dependent on two velocity arrays, u and v.

```
kernel = {0      ,v[i][j],0,
          u[i][j],0      ,u[i][j],
          0      ,v[i][j],0};
```

This kernel is used to convolute my other array called `div[i][j].`

How do I convolute a non-constant kernel using Accelerate?

Comment: It's not really a convolution if the kernel isn't constant; that said, are the values in the `u` and `v` arrays totally arbitrary, or do they come from some (relatively) simple math?

Comment: The `u` and `v` arrays are defined by other functions in the project. I have now solved this problem after I did some thorough study on convolution by splitting up the function into:

`div = {1, 0, 1}*u +{1, 0, 1}^T *v `

where `*` is the convolution operation.

Comment: So, you could do some small fixed convolutions with {1,0,1} and {1,0,1}^T, then sum the images as convA * u + convB * v.  See vDSP_vsmsma for the second pass.